# yii2 what is the purpose of data field in auth_item table provided by RBAC

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I have installed yii2-admin module by mdmsoft, I don't understand what's the use of data column in auth_item table. Can anybody here explain what's the used of that field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From `yii2/rbac/Item.php`:

```
class Item extends Object 
{
    /**
     * @var mixed the additional data associated with this item
     */
    public $data;
}
```

So this field can be used to store any auxiliary data. Rbac manages does nothing with it besides serialization/unserialization.